# Can't get git post-update hook to deploy site on bluehost

Tags: git, deployment

I’m trying to get git to deploy to my blue host account using a post-update hook script that I’ve found online.

To me it all looks correct and the git (bare repo) is receiving the files ok (they’re there when I go a git fetch or pull from the remote on blue host).

The post-update hook script is set for chmod +x execute permissions. I can’t seem to tell if the script is even being run. Is there anyway of telling?

It looks like the script just isn't being run on post-update as no file is being created where I'd expect it to be with the line echo "Script Called" >> /home1/sansgilc/public_html/_sansgil.com/dev/test

```
#!/bin/bash
#
set -ex
livepath="/home1/sansgilc/public_html/_sansgil.com/master"
devpath="/home1/sansgilc/public_html/_sansgil.com/dev"

echo "Script Called" >> /home1/sansgilc/public_html/_sansgil.com/dev/test

while read ref
do
    branch=$(echo "$ref" | cut -d/ -f3)
    if [[ master == "$branch" ]]; then
        git --work-tree=$livepath checkout -f "$branch"
        echo 'Changes pushed live.'
    elif [[ dev == "$branch" ]]; then
        git --work-tree=$devpath checkout -f "$branch"
        echo 'Changes pushed to dev.'
    fi
done
```

Comment: an easy way to tell if the code ran is to write some text to a file. try echo "Script Called" >> /path/to/file

Comment: Put `set -ex` at the top of the script.  (You might also want to run your code through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).)

Comment: Did you give the script the right name? That's something that I missed the first time I wrote a Git hook.

Comment: @Biffen the code above is inside the file named post-update. Should this not be the case? Should it be named something else or in a totally different file which is then called from post-update?

Comment: @juliushibert I can't see `post-update` mentioned [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), so maybe that's not the right name.

Comment: @Biffen good point. I've changed the script name to post-commit but still doesn't seem to be working as intended. The files aren't being checked out into the htdocs dir and there's no test file being created as part of the echo "Script Called" >> /home1/sansgilc/public_html/_sansgil.com/dev/test command.

Comment: @juliushibert If your hook is server-side, shouldn't you use `pre-receive`, `post-receive` or `update`, as per [this documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)?

Comment: @Biffen I've changed the script name to be pre-receive but still the script doesn't seem to be running as the echo file command isn't creating a new file as intended. I'm stumped.